# How to close a windows open from (javascript) by issuing window.close

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am working in Android with WebView that load javascript. I've succeeded to load the page, js and so on. Moreover I've succeeded to open a new windows by using

Previous to load the index.html, I allows the use of JS in the Activity

```
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

After the index.html with JS is loaded, I succeeded to open a windows.

```
 myWin=window.open("http://www.google.com") at js
```

But, when I issued the close signal, the page still open.

```
 myWin.close();
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement [`onCloseWindow`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onCloseWindow%28android.webkit.WebView%29) in your `WebChromeClient`. Otherwise there's no way for your app to know what closing a window means in terms of your views.

Comment: Yes, I got the message onCloseWindow, but the page still open. I missing somenthing..

Comment: Right, *you* have to close the window (in Java) since you're implementing the window. Think about what a web "window" is in your app. It probably is a `WebView`, but it could also be some other layout with some buttons for back and forward along with a `WebView`.

Answer (score 1):

try arranging the sequence of your code it matters. May be you are using javascript before enabling javascript.